# 2 apps, diffrent audio ouputs?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I would like to play music (nuryl) on the bluetooth speaker (for my son), while listening to a different app (siriusxm) via headphones. Possible? Iphone 6S.
Thank you for any information.

Comment: A similar question already has [a partial answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/connect-iphone-to-multiple-output-devices-to-play-music), but is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No - the system controls the output so it’s not easy for an app to remember a different output and override the system choice.

Unless Apple releases a new version of Workflow or some automation for iOS, you can’t script a change to the output device and then launch an app.